Dynamic Layout and Stylesheet Loading Issue in Nx Monorepo with Next.js
I'm working on a Next.js project inside an Nx monorepo. The project includes different layouts, each in its own package, and I need to load a specific layout and its corresponding global stylesheet based on the response from a fetch request.
Project Structure:
packages/layout-test/src/layout.tsx
export default async function TestLayout({children, loadStylesheet = false): PropsWithChildren<{loadStylesheet: boolean}> {
  if (loadStylesheet) {
    import('./style.scss');
  }  

  return <html>
    <body>
      WOW!
      {children}
    </body>
  </html>
} 

packages/layout-test2/src/layout.tsx
export default async function Test2Layout({children, loadStylesheet = false): PropsWithChildren<{loadStylesheet: boolean}>) {
  if (loadStylesheet) {
    import('./style.scss');
  }  

  return <html>
    <body>
      WOW 2!
      {children}
    </body>
  </html>
} 

apps/next/src/app/layout.tsx
import { TestLayout } from '@app/layout-test/layout';
import { TestLayout2 } from '@app/layout-test2/layout';

const layouts = {
  1: 'test',
  2: 'test2'
}

const SelectedLayout = async (layout: number, children) => {
  if (!layout || !layouts[layout]) {
    notFound();
  }

  const LayoutComponent = (await import(`@app/layout-${layout[id]}/layout`))
    .default;

  return <LayoutComponent>{children}</LayoutComponent>;
}

export default function RouteLayout({children}: PropsWithChildren) {
  // some conditions here
  // some informations here (parsed JWT from cookie here too)
  // some logic

  // layout information from cookie (jwt)
  const layout = 1;

  return <SelectedLayout layout={layout}>{children}</SelectedLayout>
}

Issue:
Webpack seems to be loading both stylesheets into the same chunk even though they are inside conditional imports.
Generated CSS chunk:
/* STYLE OF apps/layout.tsx generated from webpack */

/* compiled style.scss from TestLayout (which actually should be here) */
body {
   background-color: red;
}

/* NOW strange part here - TestLayout2 css which I didn't want being here, but it's here even if pass false to loadStylesheet */

body {
   background-color: green;
}

Despite only logging from the TestLayout condition, both styles are included.
Question:
How can I ensure that only the required stylesheet is loaded based on the condition and prevent Webpack from including both stylesheets?
Using .module.scss is not an option due to different Tailwind configurations and the need for global styles.
EDIT:
Found a solution and wrote a package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-webpack-multi-tailwind-layout-plugin

I am actually working on the same problem right now. I'll circle back with you once I find a solution. =)

@AlgefAlmocera I actually found a solution and wrote a package for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-webpack-multi-tailwind-layout-plugin

Glad it all worked out!
